# Inserting Child Records with Master-Detail Relationships

Tags: apex, master-detail, insert

I'm allowing a user to upload multiple files for accounts, contacts, and trades. Contact looks up to Accounts via a lookup field while trades look up to accounts via a master-detail relationship.

I've been able to insert both accounts and contacts successfully, but I'm running into issues inserting trades.

I'm inserting contacts that look up to accounts using:

```
tempContact.Account = new Account(MasterID__c=inputValuesContact[7]); (no issues)
```

and similarily trying to insert trades with:

```
tempTrade.Account__c= new Account(MasterID__c=inputvaluesTrade[0]);
```

For trades I'm getting the error:  Illegal assignment from Account to Id.

Am I missing something obvious? I've tried inserting with tempTrade.Account__r.Name but received a similar error: Illegal assignment from String to Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__c` always refers to the Id, which is similar to `AccountId`. Using `__r` is the similar to using `Account` (by contrast):

```
tempTrade.Account__r = new Account(MasterID__c=inputvaluesTrade[0]);
```

Comment: @SF2321 You're welcome! Always glad to help!